# How to tell someone their smoking is an issue

Tags: work-environment

We have a new team lead. He smokes several times a day. We have seperate smoking areas. He goes there and smokes. So far so good but unlike the other people who smoke, he gives a very bad smell. I get a headache as soon as I smell that smoke. I inquired with other people who smoke (one of them seats next to me), he told me its because they chew a chewing gum or eat chocolate or have mints. But apparently this new Team Lead doesn't do this. Should I tell him about this? If yes, how?

Comment: put an air freshener on your desk.  smoking isn't illegal, so you can't force him to stop

Comment: Or perhaps politely approach him about the issue, possibly offering some of the people's suggested solutions?

Comment: I went and told him politely. He was happy to find out why people were shying away from him. He chews some gum after smoking and stays out for sometime.

Comment: yay, happy end!

Comment: make him stop smoking